# I am trying prevent booking in sp-calender

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, office-365

iam trying to prevent double booking in a SharePoint calender, but dont now what the problem is, here is my code.

```
(function ($) {
    $(function () {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
       $("#timepicker").timepicker({
           timeFormat: 'HH:mm'
       });
       $("#datepickerto").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
       $("#timepickerTo").timepicker({
           timeFormat: 'HH:mm'

       });
    });
})(jQuery);

var context= SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = context.get_web();
var list = web.get_lists();
var targetList;

function createItem() {

    targetList = list.getByTitle('AppbokningarList');

    var listItemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
    this.newItem = targetList.addItem(listItemCreateInfo);

    var listItemTitle = document.getElementById('Textrubrik').value;
    alert(listItemTitle);

    var listItemCustom = document.getElementById('datepicker').value;
    alert(listItemCustom);

    var listItemFromTime = document.getElementById('timepicker').value;
    alert(listItemFromTime);

    var listItemtoDate = document.getElementById('datepickerto').value;
    alert(listItemtoDate);

    var listItemToTime = document.getElementById('timepickerTo').value;
    alert(listItemToTime);

    var listItemBeskrivning = document.getElementById('Textbeskrivning').value;
    alert(listItemBeskrivning);
    newItem.set_item('Title', listItemTitle);
    var result = listItemCustom + "T" + listItemFromTime + "Z";
    newItem.set_item('EventDate', result);
    var result2 = listItemtoDate + "T" + listItemToTime + "Z";
    newItem.set_item('EndDate', result2);
    newItem.set_item('Description', listItemBeskrivning);

    newItem.update();
    context.load(newItem);

    var frDate = new Date(result),
      tDate = new Date(result2),
      camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery(),
      collListItem, strViewXml;


    strViewXml = "<View><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='EventDate'/></OrderBy><Where><And><Lt><FieldRef Name='EndDate'/>";
    strViewXml += "<Value Type='DateTime'>" + tDate.toISOString() + "</Value></Lt><Gt><FieldRef Name='EventDate'/>";
    strViewXml += "<Value Type='DateTime'>" + frDate.toISOString() + "</Value></Gt></And></Where></Query></View>";



    camlQuery.set_viewXml(strViewXml);
    collListItem = targetList.getItems(camlQuery);
    context.load(collListItem);

    context.executeQueryAsync(
               function () {

                   if (collListItem.get_count() > 0) {
                       alert('there is already an event on this day');

                   } else {
                       alert('go ahead and create the event the user wants');

                   }
               },
               function (sender, args) {
                   alert( args.get_message());
               }
       );
}
```

Comment: Have you tried this: http://spjsblog.com/2012/02/25/spjs-resource-management-no-more-double-booking/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `strViewXml` only checks for events that are completely inside an existing event.  So if there's an existing booking from 9am-4pm and you try to create a booking from 8am-5pm, it doesn't look like your query will catch that. You'll need an OR statement which marks the following as conflicts:

- The new start date is less than or equal to the existing start and the new end is greater than the existing start
- The new start date is greater than or equal to the existing start and less than the existing end